# Setting the Values of Tuple types in C++

Tags: c++11

Suppose I have some tuple:

`tuple<int, float>`

How would I set the value of the int and float, respectively.  Like:

int = 4, float = 3.45?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::tuple<int, float> t;

// set int to 4
std::get<0>(t) = 4;

// set float to 3.45
std::get<1>(t) = 3.45;

// set both values
t = std::make_tuple(4, 3.45);
```

Since C++14, you can also index tuples by type, if the type is unique within the tuple. That means, you can write code as follows:

```
// set int to 4
std::get<int>(t) = 4;

// set float to 3.45
std::get<float>(t) = 3.45;
```